# kafka Unrecognized token 'Test': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

in jhipster 5.3.4 i have started kafka with docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    #image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0
    #image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic-jhipster:1:1"
    ports:
        - 9092:9092
```

One Gateway with kafka configuration producer,
One microservice with kafka configuration consumer,
all work fine, from gateway i can send messagge to consumer, but in consumer every minutes, i receive the following error in console:

```
[container-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = topic-jhipster, partition = 0, offset = 44, CreateTime = 1537526418149, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 53, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [123, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 34, 44, 34, 115, 117, 98, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 115, 111, 110, 34, 44, 34, 112, 97, 114, 97, 109, 101, 116, 101, 114, 115, 34, 58, 123, 125, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 99, 114, 101, 116, 101, 34, 58, 116, 114, 117, 101, 44, 34, 119, 105, 108, 100, 99, 97, 114, 100, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 34, 119, 105, 108, 100, 99, 97, 114, 100, 83, 117, 98, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 34, 99, 104, 97, 114, 115, 101, 116, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 125]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 77, 105, 109, 101, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@5b00f255)
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'Test': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (byte[])"Test message from gw1 sent at 2018-09-21T12:40:18.148"; line: 1, column: 6]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Test': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (byte[])"Test message from gw1 sent at 2018-09-21T12:40:18.148"; line: 1, column: 6]
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:235)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertFromInternal(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:97)
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:70)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:137)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:116)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:109)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:70)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:387)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:364)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1077)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:999)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:867)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:725)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Test': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"Test message from gw1 sent at 2018-09-21T12:40:18.148"; line: 1, column: 6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:679)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3526)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2621)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:826)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3121)
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:222)
... 37 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)

You need to show your `@StreamListener` but clearly, it is attempting to decode JSON to some object...

> at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:222)

When your message is clearly not JSON...

```
Test message from gw1 sent at 2018-09-21T12:40:18.148
```

Comment: Could you please guide here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487242/org-springframework-messaging-converter-messageconversionexception-could-not-re?